# How to run Firefox extension using Firefox Developer Edition and jpm?

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-edition

I'm having some inconvenient with current release Firefox version and want to switch to Dev edition to developing my extension.

I've tried the tutorial in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Selecting_a_browser_version) but doesn't work. The example is for nightly build, which I guess is the folder name, but replace it doesn't work. And also created a system environment doesn't help too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-b` expects the path to the executable, not the folder. On Windows, I used `jpm run -b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"` and it worked fine.

Comment: Or `jpm run -b /bin/firefox-developer` if on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can set the `JPM_FIREFOX_BINARY` environment variable with the path to the version of Firefox you want to run, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe`. So when you invoke `jpm run` or `jpm test` without the -b option, jpm first checks `JPM_FIREFOX_BINARY`, and use this as the path if it is set.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Selecting_a_browser_version